# How to list all signatures with signtool.exe while verifying against the kernel signing policy

Tags: windows, code-signing, signtool, authenticode

So I am signing a binary using signtool from the Windows SDK 8.1:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /i Symantec /ac C:\utils\MSCV-VSClass3.cer /ph /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" "foo.exe"
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: foo.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /i Symantec /ac C:\utils\MSCV-VSClass3.cer /ph /fd sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa" /td sha256 /as "foo.exe"
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: foo.exe
```

When I look at it in the file properties, I can see the correct result.

However, when I use `verify` with this very `signtool` I get, depending on the passed parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" verify /all "foo.exe"
File: foo.exe
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
        certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
        certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

With `/pa` and `/pa /all` I can see both timestamps:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" verify /pa "foo.exe"
File: foo.exe
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
0      sha1       Authenticode

Successfully verified: foo.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" verify /pa /all "foo.exe"
File: foo.exe
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
0      sha1       Authenticode
1      sha256     RFC3161
```

but when trying to use `/kp` to verify against the kernel signing policy, `signtool` refuses to run that along with `/all`:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" verify /kp /all "foo.exe"
SignTool Error: The /all option is incompatible with the /kp option.
```

So I have two questions:

1. is this a defect (that `/kp` and `/all` don't work together)?
2. is there a better way than to call `signtool verify` twice, once with `/pa /all` and once with `/kp` to *see* all timestamps *and* verify against the kernel signing policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently stumbled upon the same issue with `/kp` and `/all`, and completely by chance discovered that the order of arguments is important. If I specify `/kp /all`, I get `The /all option is incompatible with the /kp option`. But if I pass `/all /kp`, verification works smoothly: it enumerates all signatures in the file and checks them all.